# Uitableview Photos Show Up then turn black

Tags: facebook-graph-api, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I am currently working with an UITableview which loads a users wall feed from Facebook. The problem I have is, the images that get put into the tableview load up fine but when the user scrolls, they turn completely black. Here is my cellForRow Method:

```
 if ([[objectTypes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"photo"]) {
    //this is a picture

    if ([facebookPictureObjectIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) 
                    {
                        if ([sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) {
                            if ([[sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] rangeOfString:[facebookPictureObjectIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]].location != NSNotFound) {

                                imageCell.imageview.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];
                                NSLog(@"source array objectwith image ID: %@",[facebookPictureObjectIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);


                            }else {


                                NSLog(@"Same Image object id is: %@", [facebookPictureObjectIDs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);


                            }

                        }   else {
                            NSLog(@"Source Array object NIL NIL NIL");

                        }                 

                    }else {
                        NSLog(@"Else Called");
                    }

    [imageCell layoutSubviews];
    returnCell = imageCell;
   }
```

Thanks for any help :)